# How to hide content view from content page view model(Xamarin forms,freshmvvm)

Tags: xamarin.forms, fody, freshmvvm

I am adding like this content view which is having its own view model.I want to handle its visibility from view model of content page.

```
    <ContentPage>
    <local:ContentView1 IsVisible="{Binding IsContentViewVisible}"/>
    </ContentPage>
```

Here is page's view model binding for content view's hiding and showing
public bool IsContentViewVisible{get;set;}
and then i am using it by giving true or false.
I am using Fody so there is no need of INotifyPropertyChanged I assume.

Comment: why isn't `IsContentViewVisible` working for you?

Comment: dont knw that is the question.I can see the binding happening properly but the view is not hiding

Comment: where is the code for your VM?  Is your page's BindingContext set correctly?  Does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I am using Fody so no need for INotifyPropertyChanged.In view model i have created property as 'public bool IsContentViewVisible{get;set;}' and i am setting true or false to this

Comment: with Fody your class still needs to implement INPC - see https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged#overview

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Through the [document](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged#overview),

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you ViewModel:

**NOTE: All classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged will have notification code injected into property setters.**